# Is recursion preferred in this situation?

Tags: c, performance, recursion

Suppose we have a string of characters and we want to print it in reverse order. Recursion seems to be the faster choice in this case because the string is "walked" once, while the usual loop approach does it twice.

Is there any reason not to prefer recursion for these kind of problems? Does recursion pose some sort of disadvantage in case of big input?

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printReverse_1(const char *str)
{
    if (!*str)
        return;

    printReverse_1(str + 1);
    putchar(*str);
}

void printReverse_2(const char *str)
{
    const char *tmp = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    while (tmp > str)
    {
        putchar(*tmp--);
    }
    putchar(*tmp);
}

int main(void)
{
    printReverse_1("abc");
    putchar('\n');

    printReverse_2("abc");
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recursion is never preferred if there is a simple nonrecursive solution.

Comment: "Recursion seems to be the faster choice ...." Well, not sure about that - remember that each function call has some overhead. In other words - the overhead of many recursive function calls may be more expensive than `strlen`

Comment: `const char *tmp = str + strlen(str) - 1;` is UB when `str[0] == 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any reason not to prefer recursion in these kind of problems? Does recursion pose some sort of disadvantage in case of big input?

Recursion creates a new [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) for each function invocation. For large inputs it may run out of stack space. Prefer iteration to recursion, when possible.

Comment: ... and the creation of te stack frame also takes some time.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Could you quantify that time?

Comment: Very difficult to quantify, but it definitely takes _some_ time. But the compiler may as well optimize out the recursion, especially if it is tail recursion.

Comment: Also, function calls are very slow, which the OP seems not to be taking into consideration.  Concerns about exhausting available memory notwithstanding, the OP is probably mistaken about the recursive alternative having a performance advantage.

Answer (score 4):

> Recursion seems to be the faster choice in this case because the string is "walked" once, while the usual loop approach does it twice.

When it comes to performance, never assume anything. Test both approaches and measure. But as a rule of thumb, it's quicker with loops than recursion, since recursion means function calls and setting up stack frames.

> Is there any reason not to prefer recursion in these kind of problems? Does recursion pose some sort of disadvantage in case of big input?

In general, the benefit of recursion is that they are easy to write and easy to read. They are very rarely preferable for performance reasons. And their biggest drawback is that they tend to eat up the stack like crazy.

In this particular situation, it's unlikely that performance actually is an issue. But if it is, it's also likely that the call to `putchar` is the biggest problem because you call it once for every character. So in this particular example, you really missed the elephant in the room. Function calls can be expensive.

In order to do this as fast as possible, I'd try this:

```
void printReverse_3(const char *str)
{
        const size_t len = strlen(str);
        // alloca may blow the stack. Use malloc if you want to use this on                                                                                                                                                                   
        // huge strings                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        char *tmp = alloca(len + 1);

        tmp[len]='\0';
        str = &str[len];

        for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
                str--;
                tmp[i] = *str;
        }

        printf("%s", tmp);
}
```

I have not tried this out, but I do suspect that it is quicker. You could change `printf` for `puts` since that function is quicker, but `puts` adds a newline afterwards, so it would not have been equivalent to your functions.

Comment: `str = &str[len-1];` is UB when original `str[0] == 0`.  Could use `str = &str[len];` and pre-decrement _in the loop_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good catch! Fixed it.

Comment: Er,  `str = &str[len]; str--;` remains UB.  Suggest `str = &str[len]; for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++) { str--;  tmp[i] = *str;  }`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Are you really sure? Doesn't it become UB when you dereference it? Fixed it btw, since it looks better. But I'm not convinced it's UB.

Comment: Forming a pointer one past on the end is OK.  Forming a pointer before the beginning of the array is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Interesting. Do you have some source for that?

Comment: It is UB by omission.   Pointer math addition is only specified within an array, or 1 past.  Code like `char *s = "abc"; char *t = s -1;` is UB.  You could post a question if you like.  See c17 § 6.5.6 8,9

Comment: This is covered in the definition of pointer arithmetic in [paragraph 6.5.6/8 of the Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8).  (That's a link to C11, but nothing about this changed in C18.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Perfect. Thanks. Saved me a question. :)

Comment: @klutt - could your code benefit from using `memchr` instead of `strlen`? Microsoft (Visual Studio 2017) compiler has a naive implementation of `strlen`, while `memchr` appears to work on multi-byte chunks; not sure about other compilers.

Comment: @VladFeinstein As I wrote in the beginning. Try it and measure. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to @klutt; posting this as an answer instead of the comment to make the code readable.

Using `memchr` instead of `strlen` for a 10,000,000 character string takes 1.5us-1.8us compared to 3.2us-3.4us, or about half the time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

size_t len(const char* p)
{
  //return strlen(p);
  char* end = (char*)memchr(p, '\0', -1);
  return end - p;
}

int main()
{
  const int block = 10'000'000;
  std::vector<char> v(block, 'x');
  v[block - 1] = 0;
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  size_t l = len(&v[0]);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "len() took "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
    << " microseconds\n";
  return l;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged `C` not `C++` :)

Comment: @machine_1 Oh, I've missed that. However, only my benchmarking is C++, both `memchr` and `strlen` are C-runtime functions - right?